# Can connect through WiFi but not through LAN

Tags: router, lan

My sysadmin recently passed away very suddenly so we're in a bind here. Network is not working. Strangely we can connect through WiFi but not through LAN. Our network is a maze of switches and hubs and I don't have a topology of it. If I connect through LAN I am connected to the gateway but can't ping anywhere. Please see attachment. Anyone know what's going on? Speaking of topology, does anyone know of a good preferably free network topology map for OSX? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How big is the network? Is there any external hosting?

Comment: It's not that big. Maybe 50 computers? Though they're not always on at the same time. What does external hosting mean?

Comment: Can you logon to the admin panel of the router at 192.168.1.1?

Comment: Not when im on lan but yes on wifi